# SQL Insert newlines and formatting data

Tags: sql-server-2005

A, B, C, D and E are five columns in a table. I need output like:

```
A
newline
B
newline
C
newline
D
newline
E
```

But there cannot be two newlines between two columns(if one is null), for eg -

```
A
newline
D
newline
E
```

So if there is no data in column B there should be no newline corresponding to B.
Right now I am thinking of a scaler function with If else loops. Any better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE operator i believe.
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN Video_Title IS NOT NULL THEN
       Video_Title + '\n'
       ELSE
       ''      
       END + 

       CASE WHEN Author IS NOT NULL THEN
       Author + '\n'
       ELSE
       ''   
       END +


       CASE WHEN URL IS NOT NULL THEN
       URL + '\n'
       ELSE
       ''   
       END   
FROM Videos
```

This is something i just tried with my own database, but I think something like this should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @CRLF CHAR(2)

SET @CRLF = CHAR(10)+ CHAR(13);

WITH t AS
(
SELECT 'A' AS A,'B' AS B, 'C' AS C, 'D' AS D, 'E' AS E UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS A,NULL AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D, 'E' AS E UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS A,NULL AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D, NULL AS E
)
SELECT 
ISNULL(STUFF(ISNULL(@CRLF + A,'') + ISNULL(@CRLF + B,'') + ISNULL(@CRLF + C,'') + ISNULL(@CRLF + D,'') +ISNULL(@CRLF + E,'')  , 1, 2, ''),'')
FROM t
```